# iOS 11 Facebook SignIn is showing an initial system alert

Tags: ios, ios11

Preparing an app for iOS 11, I noticed there is a system alert showing up every time the user click on the "Facebook login" button. Does somebody know how to prevent this alert from appearing?. Now Social Networks integrations have been removed from the system and together with the Safari View Controller cookies storage changes (to not be shared) it sounds Apple has also added this extra alert to the sign up - sign in flow whenever you try to connect with Facebook. Has some body experienced the same issue in your apps?. Thanks for your comments.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an *issue*. It's by design. Part of the authorization workflow when working with `SFAuthenticationSession` in iOS 11+ and you can't avoid it since it's a user permission request.

> If an application uses SFAuthenticationSession, **users are prompted by a dialog to give explicit consent**, allowing the application to access the website's data in Safari.
>
> > SFAuthenticationSession docs

Comment: I'm noticing that this isn't the case with the Pinterest app (and likely others), i.e. there's no `SFAuthenticationSession` alert before bringing up `facebook.com` for login. Do you know why their app does not present this alert, @nathan?

Comment: I've reported this issue to Apple and Facebook, Apple says it's as intended,as @nathan mentioned. FB confirmed they actually use SafariViewController and they can't prevent the alert either are plans to change the auth flow, which is really inconvenient since users need to see that again and again. In addition the credentials are not autocompleted when the signup view from FB is presented. Also, Twitter in their Kit is using SFVC. I guess also Twitter integration is going to present the same behaviour (https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/log-in-with-twitter).

Comment: The only way I found to prevent the alert is downgrading the FB version SDK to 4.19.0 (that's the one I tried - not sure about all the other versions in between). But that means of course losing all the latest months bug fixing

Comment: bummer. so any app that isn't currently showing the `SFAuthenticationSession` alert is simply using an old FB SDK. thanks for the info, @BarbaraRodeker and @nathan — I suppose we'll just have to monitor this to see if Apple changes their mind.

Comment: those are at least the results from my tests with 4.25.0 , 4.27.0 & 4.19.0 versions of FB SDK.

Comment: Would be really nice if Apple allowed to suppress this alert as long as a link to the sophisticated privacy policy is provided. Nothing wrong with having it, but if I tell users in my login screen "by proceeding you agree with our privacy policy" and then this popup comes up it makes little sense...