# New facebook login redirect flow on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

As of iOS 11, I'm seeing a new login flow when using FBSDKLoginKit and FBSDKCoreKit. I realize apple's recent change(s) to how apps talk with each other re: facebook credentials mean we first have to go through safari during the authentication flow... but for some reason I'm seeing the below alert dialog (see first and second screenshots) even though in other apps that feature facebook login, I'm able to go directly to facebook.com and am then offered the choice to either authenticate through the native Facebook app *or* log in with email/password (see second screenshot).

Does anyone know why I'm seeing this flow on my app but am seeing a different flow on pretty much every other app that I've looked at that's implemented facebook login? I've followed the flow listed on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios so I'm pretty much stumped. Thanks in advance.

[image: Login screen for FB iOS SDK]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the `loginBehavior` ? See https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginManager.h#L72  That alert is part of iOS 11' `SFAuthenticationSession` auth flow

Comment: dang, @nathan! thanks. switching from `FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemNative` to either `FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemBrowser` or `FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount` solves the "missing the Log in with the Facebook App" button — but the `SFAuthenticationSession` alert is still there. switching to `FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemWeb` gets rid of the `SFAuthenticationSession` alert, but we're still missing the "Log in with the Facebook App" button. Is there any way to not have the alert but have the "Log in with the Facebook App" button (similar to the Breather app)?

Comment: ah, I see you've already answered this elsewhere, @nathan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858774/ios-11-facebook-signin-is-showing-an-initial-system-alert

Comment: Partly true. I’m not sure why the login kit won’t open the app (if installed) when Native is used, instead of Safari.

Comment: @nathan feel free to answer this question with what you said above and I'll go ahead and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the `loginBehavior` of the login manager. See https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginManager.h#L72. That alert is part of iOS 11' SFAuthenticationSession auth flow.

> ```
> /**
>   This is the default behavior, and indicates logging in through the native
>  Facebook app may be used. The SDK may still use Safari instead.
>  */
> case native
> /**
>   Attempts log in through the Safari or SFSafariViewController, if available.
>  */
> case browser
> /**
>   Attempts log in through the Facebook account currently signed in through
>  the device Settings.
>  @note If the account is not available to the app (either not configured by user or
>  as determined by the SDK) this behavior falls back to \c .native.
>  */
> case systemAccount
> /**
>   Attempts log in through a modal \c UIWebView pop up
>  @note This behavior is only available to certain types of apps. Please check the Facebook
>  Platform Policy to verify your app meets the restrictions.
>  */
> case web
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is an **intended behaviour**, confirmed to me by Apple & Facebook. It's the implementation and flow of SafariViewController authentication, it's documented by Apple too (the system alert) & the third screenshot you post it's most probably an app using an old version of Facebook SDK. Please checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858774/ios-11-facebook-signin-is-showing-an-initial-system-alert/45864187?noredirect=1#comment80142909_45864187) I opened some weeks ago with the same UX you describe, then you'll find more comments & links to the proper documentation. You can not do nothing in your code to prevent the system alert to appear, unless you downgrade the FB version.